# What to do with [equals] and [equality]

Tags: discussion, tags

So there is [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality):

> Test to determine if two or more items are either the exact same item or of equal values.

and [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals):

> Refers to Java equals method, indicating whether some object is "equal to" this one.

The thing about that is, looking over [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309554/get-all-related-tags-by-tag?TagID=5678) for [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals):

```
TagName                   Count 
------------------------- ----- 
java                      969   
c#                        253   
hashcode                  252   
string                    179   
object                    79    
arrays                    76    
.net                      72    
equality                  66    
javascript                64
```

... and so on, including [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), ad nauseam. It's clear that when users are asking questions and tagging them as such are paying no mind to the description.

Moreover the [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) tag has a [large number](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309554/get-all-related-tags-by-tag?TagID=4197) of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions.

So, what to do? (in no particular order of preference, and not all mutually exclusive)

1. <strike>Clean up both tags, retagging non-Java [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) questions with [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality), and Java [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) questions with [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) as appropriate.</strike>
2. Make [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) a synonym with [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality).
3. Encourage use of [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) with an appropriate language tag.
4. <strike>Nothing.</strike>
5. Burninate (all the peasants!)
6. Something else I haven't thought of?

Comment: I'm in favor of option #2, because there is no intuitive reason to expect [equals] to refer specifically to the Java method. If it's really important to have a tag for that specifically, someone can make a [java-equals] tag.

Comment: [Equals] equals [Equality]?

Comment: A combination of [java] and [equality] should be used instead of [equals] which somehow implies Java. Merge them into [equality] and get rid of the language-specific notion.

Comment: C# objects also have an `Equals()` method.  Don't make [java-equals] and [c#-equals] tags; that's completely unnecessary.  The question will already  have a c# or java tag on it.  Yes, you can search on multiple tags.  No, you don't need the ability to follow these; who is going to follow something that specific?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [c-equals], [cpp-equals], [perl-equals], [unicorn-equals], [adnauseam-equals]...

Comment: Option 2 is best option here.

Comment: I say we burn the dirty Commie tags. (Sincerely, a proud Amurikan)

Comment: I'm with @QPaysTaxes here.  Is it really possible to be an expert in either of these things?

Comment: What about option 6: Add `Equals`, `isEqualTo`, `isEqualToString`, `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`,`Equal`, `eq?`, `eqv?`, `equal?`, etc. tags for all the other specific equality functions in every other language, just like `equals` for Java? I think if that's ridiculous, then so are options 1 and 4.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no reason, apart from the description, for [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) to be Java specific. Even more, I don't believe tagging a question with the function you have questions about is usefull. The language ([java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) + the subject ([equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality)) says enough/more.

So I propose to merge [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) into [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) and making it a synonym.

Comment: However, there might be a difference between the `.equals` method in OOP and the generic concept(s) of equality. Not sure though whether we we really needed to distinguish them and how to draw a line.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't see what OOP has to do with anything. Plenty of non-OO languages also have multiple different equality tests, like Lisp's `eq` vs. `eql` vs. `equal` vs. `equalp`.

Comment: @Bergi [java] and [equality] or [javascript] and [equality] say more than [equals] or [triple-equals]

Comment: @abarnert: I just meant that [equals] might be used for anything that has to do with a `.equals` *object method*. But you're right, with that reasoning we'd need another tag for every single equality function name, and that would get out of hand. Synonymize them all!

Comment: @Bergi: I was more asking how a `.equals` object method is any different from an `equals` function (or an `equals:` object method not spelled with dot syntax, or an `equals` Dylan-style-OO multimethod that dispatches on both objects instead of just one, and so on). But it doesn't really matter; you're right that the point I accidentally made overwhelms the point I was intending to make. :)

Comment: These are closely enough related terms (mathematically speaking) that I see no value in having separate tags for them in a programming Q&A site.  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)), "The equality between A and B is written A = B, and pronounced A equals B."  So "equals" is the operator for the "equality" relationship, and thus falls under the "equality" umbrella.

Answer (score 4):

## Option 5: burnination

What does it mean to be a master of [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality)? I know of only one:

[image: Monty Python and the Holy Grail "she's a witch" scene]
<sub>- - -   She's a Witch! scene from Monty Python and the Holy Grail</sub>

…and he did about as much good as these tags are doing.

Each tag has 7 followers. If I had to hazard a guess, this either happened accidentally or because of this meta post.

A cursory glance at the newest questions reveals that the tag is anything but focused:

[image: "newest questions under equality tag"]

The fact of the matter is that [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) and [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) add nothing to the question. These tags are covered by a good title and language-appropriate tags. Having the OP indicate that (s)he is having `equality` issues does not help in answering the question.

Honestly, when was the last time you said to yourself

> This question is tagged [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality)!!! I **must** answer this one!!!

When was the last time you really even paid much attention to the fact that a question was tagged [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) or [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals)?

If I came across a question with one of those tags, there's a 99.999% chance I'd remove it. It's just clutter.

We have no reason to continue to use these tags.

## tl;dr these tags should be `burninated`*:

[image: "we have found a witch, may we burn her?" — Monty Python and the Holy Grail "she's a witch scene" meme]

<sup>*or somehow/otherwise discouraged</sup>

Comment: I'd call John Locke a master of equality. And some of his successors, like Thomas Jefferson. I'm not sure I'd want them helping me with my code, but then I don't want to speak for the Java community; they seem to like long, detailed declarations of things that are self-evident more than I do.

Comment: This tag doesn't seem like it meets all the criteria for burnination laid out in the FAQ: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1108305