# Retag [equals] to [equality]

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

The [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) tag refers to the Java [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method:

> Refers to Java equals method, indicating whether some object is "equal to" this one.

Per [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292179/what-to-do-with-equals-and-equality) from 5 years ago, the [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) tag is unnecessarily Java-specific, and often used in non-Java questions.  It appears that this has not changed in the intervening time.  The answer with by far the most upvotes (41 upvotes, 0 downvotes) was to make `equals` a synonym for `equality`, dropping the Java-specific nature in the process.

> There is no reason, apart from the description, for [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) to be Java specific. Even more, I don't believe tagging a question with the function you have questions about is usefull. The language ([java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) + the subject ([equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality)) says enough/more.
>
> So I propose to merge [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) into [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) and making it a synonym.

I do not have a score of 5 in the tag, so I cannot suggest the synonym.  I am therefore requesting someone with sufficient privileges to make [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals) a synonym for [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) (with [equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality) being the primary tag).

Comment: Isn't there a mathematical difference between these terms? [_Equality (mathematics)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics))
Probably, it's better to generalize the tag wiki text for [tag:equals], and kick the Java languange "binding" out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ — From that Wikipedia article, "equals" is the name of the equality operator: "The equality between A and B is written A = B, and pronounced A equals B."  So I would say that they refer to the same mathematical concept.  One is the term for the relationship, and the other the term for the operator expressing that relationship.  I don't see value from a programming Q&A perspective of having separate tags for the relationship and its operator.  The difference is subtle enough that users are unlikely to correctly draw the distinction when tagging.

Comment: _"from a programming Q&A perspective of having separate tags for the relationship and its operator"_ Of course that makes sense, especially for having a generic progrmming language distinction for these, ***equal operators*** and ***equality relationships*** are expressed totally different amongst OOP oriented programming languages.

Comment: I don't understand.  Let's take Java as an example.  Java has two main types of equality: `==` (numerical/boolean/object reference) and `.equals` (object equivalence).  From a mathematical perspective, `==` and `.equals` would be the equality operator (i.e. "equals").  Both of them (when used correctly) represent equality.  How is it useful, practically speaking, to be able to follow the tag of one but not the other, or search the tag of one or not the other, or do any of the other things tagging is designed to do?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As a way of direct analogy, this would be just like having separate `[plus]` and `[addition]` tags, or `[times]` and [`multiplication`] tags.  However, none of the four basic mathematical operations have a tag for their operator at all, just for the operation as a whole.  In this context, it would be better if `[equals]` didn't exist at all.  However, given the high bar for burnination, a tag synonym seems the appropriate approach.